# Cant connect to local pyftpdlib FTP server: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib, pyftpdlib

I am trying to upload/download file to local FTP server, but it gives me the error mentioned in title.
For server I am using `pyftpdlib`:

```
import os

from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer

# instantiate a dummy authorizer 
authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()

# instantiate anonymous user to current directory
authorizer.add_anonymous(os.getcwd())

# FTP handler class
handler = FTPHandler
handler.authorizer = authorizer

# setup server on localhost, port = 21
address = ('', 21)
server = FTPServer(address, handler)

# set a limit for connections
server.max_cons = 10
server.max_cons_per_ip = 3

# start ftp server
server.serve_forever()
```

Here is client code:

```
from ftplib import FTP

# connect to FTP server
client = FTP(host="127.0.0.1")
client.login()

# list the contents of directory
client.retrlines('LIST')
```

But the `FTP` constructor throws:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Initially I thought it was port issue (I did not specify port from client when connected), so changed server port to 21, which I believe is default port.

When running server code, I get firewall alert, but when I give it the permission it runs normally. How can I connect to server from the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `''` as an address would do on the server side. Either it is a wrong value in the first place. Or it may resolve to a different IP address than the `127.0.0.1`. You should use the same value both on server and client side.

I'd start with `127.0.0.1` on the server side.

```
address = ('127.0.0.1', 21)
```